# Django error trying to connect to view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to test a simple view I wrote in Django. I tried connecting to the view test_view with url pattern `url(r'^test_view$',test_view)`. I used curl to do this, with the command 
`curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_view`, but I get back `500` errors every time I try this command. Is my url pattern incorrect? Am I calling it incorrectly. I'm new to django and have just been following tutorials, but I haven't strayed from those tutorials.

I'm running the server on a virtual environment with South installed as well, from a directory one level higher than the urls.py and views.py files.

Comment: Set `DEBUG=True` in settings and see if an error would come out, and if yes, show what does it show. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try via the browser?

Comment: Running through the browser helped. It was an issue with not importing, the browser gave me the name error which let me determine that. Not sure how to interpret the debug output.